# NavigationBar Button is not displaying

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have one view controller in that I have navigation bar.
I have set its tint-color white. Now I am presenting image-picker view and paypal page from that view controller.
When image-picker view or paypal view appears, its navigation bar not displaying button(cancel button by default).
Button is there , but its color is set to white. How to solve that issue? Can I change color of image-picker view?
I am displaying Navigation bar like this:

```
 PaymentViewController *paymentVC=[[PaymentViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PaymentViewController" bundle:nil];
 UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:paymentVC];
 if ([navController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector( setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)])
 {
       UIImage *navBarImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar"];
       [navController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:navBarImg forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
 }
 [self.tabBar presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: can you show me code of navigationBar button added?

Answer (score 0):

Write below code instead:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"top_bar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
PaymentViewController *paymentVC=[[PaymentViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PaymentViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:paymentVC];
[self.tabBar presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: ok....this chagnged navigation bar image of paypal and imagepickerview...but what if I dont want to change them display as it is....

Comment: just inherit both the classes. In viewWillAppear, remove the appearance and in viewDidDisappear, apply it again.